# Ionic2 Google Maps JS SDK does not work on Ionic View

Tags: android, google-maps, typescript, ionic2, ionic-view

I made an app that uses Google Maps Javascript SDK. It works perfectly when using "`ionic serve`" to browser, emulator and connected device (Android 6 and iOS 10). Works well when using "`ionic run android`" too.  But when I send to Ionic View the maps feature does not appear.
I've already put my API key and tried using enableProdMode(), but nothing makes the maps feature be showed.
Any suggestion ?

My software versions :

```
OSX Sierra
ionic 2.2.3
cordova 7.0.1
node 6.9.1
npm 4.2.0
```

Also I would like to know if there is any way to debug the app in Ionic View.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you can show us some code. Its hard to find the issue without. 
In my case i forgot to add the `geolocation` plugin. Add with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`. 
This could help you too:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-google-maps-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined/22550/6

Comment: Here is the link where you can see the code used on this feature.
https://github.com/alanoteles/mapabeauty-ionic
Is important to say that this code is working on the device plugged on the machine, using "ionic run android". The issue happend only on Ionic View.

Comment: here is the installed plugins :   
$ cordova plugin list   
com.googlemaps.ios 2.2.0-fixed "Google Maps SDK for iOS"  
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"  
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"  
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"  
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"  
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.4.0 "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin"  
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"  
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"  
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"   
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"  
 {}

Comment: ty ´declare var google´ at the top. like the imports